# Execute URL Google Distance Matrix Api and Recover Data Json

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to run a query at URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=-23.601646,-46.650278&destinations=-22.907560,-43.481736&key=CODE_KEY
```

And then retrieve the data Json.

What changes in the URL is the source and destination coordinates that are reported.

I tried that way and it did not work out.

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=-23.601646,-46.650278&destinations=-22.907560,-43.481736&key=CODE_KEY");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String nameAdress = jObject.getString("destination_addresses");

            /*Show in TextView*/ 
            tvDistancia.setText(nameAdress);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        }
        /*finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }*/
```

Result json:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Unnamed Road - Senador Camará, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "R. João de Castilho, 31 - Vila Clementino, São Paulo - SP, 04041-070, Brasil"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "412 km",
                  "value" : 411915
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 horas 46 minutos",
                  "value" : 20780
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Documentation: [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start?hl=pt-br)

Comment: What is the error that is being reported in this case?

Comment: says that this line is null: JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); @DheerajNair